# Modular testing requirement file Node.js

Tags: node.js, module, require, modular

I cannot think of a proper way to ask Google this... I want to create a modular file for testing requirement files so I do not have to constantly require chai, require sinon, require etc on each page... maybe my coffee isn't strong enough but I know before that export can work I need to destructure it all into an object... I just have all the `const chai = require('chai');`, etc. on one page and just want to be able to `module.exports = { testRequirements };` and import that where I need it... Direct me, oh wise devs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not connected to a dev environment to test, but what about:

```
const chai = require('chai');
etc...

var testRequirements = {
  chai,
  mocha,
  ...
}

module.exports = testRequirements;
```

Then you should be able to import testRequirements and refer to testRequirements.mocha etc...

Comment: Embarrassed I couldn't just make that happen... XD Thank you